# memory corruption error

Tags: c++, string, malloc, memory-corruption

EDITED: spotted other part of code that causes this error:

```
void error(std::string str)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str.c_str());
}
```

when I use it like that:

```
error("name " + id + " has already appeared");
```

I get the error:

```
malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x00000000014c7310 ***
```

Comment: Please produce an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: You also do not need to call `map::find`.  The `map::insert` function does everything your code does now, but safely.  `if (!(map_pointer->insert(make_pair(id, value)).second)) { // element already exists }`

Comment: But I need to do some action if the key was already there.

Comment: @niczka - I guess you didn't read my comment.  When you call `insert`, a `std::pair` is returned to you.  The `second` tells if the element already existed.  Please see this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Comment: @niczka - If you changed your code to use `map::insert`, then you will see that a simple call to `insert` shouldn't fail whatsoever.  If it does, then the issue is that your pointer is invalid, or that your `some_value` has bad/weird copy semantics when attempting to make a copy of the value.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: true. Sorry about adding confusion. Somehow I got confused by the pointer thing (comment removed).

Comment: this part of code was correct, I'm sorry, I've edited the question.

Comment: @niczka - If a simple piece of code causes such problems, then you have a fundamental issue with pointer/memory mismanagement somewhere in your program.  The only advice I can give you is to go over your code and see where you're using dynamically allocated memory and see whether it can be replaced with objects, containers, smart pointers, etc.  Then the chance of corruptions like this become greatly reduced, if not eliminated altogether.

Comment: I've found the place in my code. I'm using a map of lists, but I create the lists when I need them - in the local scope. Do you have any advice how to do it properly, but only when I need them?